# Find the true solution to this second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the true solution to the problem

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = -\frac{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}{y}$$

with boundary conditions

$$y(1)=2.58,\ y(2)=4.42.$$

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite this, using ' to denote differentiation with respect to $x$, as $$y'' = -\frac{(y')^2}{y}$$ which can be rearranged to give $$y''y + (y')^2 = 0.$$ Now note that $$(y^2)' = 2yy'$$ and $$(y^2)'' = (2yy')' = 2(y')^2 + 2yy''.$$ So your differential equation reduces to $$\frac{1}{2}(y^2)'' = 0$$ which you should be able to solve for $y^2$. Then apply the initial conditions.

Comment: do you intergrate
$$1/2(y^2)''=0$$
twice to get
$$1/24 y^4 =C_1 x+C_2$$

Comment: You do integrate (I would say antidifferentiate) twice, but you have done it incorrectly. First notice that we can multiply both sides of the final DE in my answer by $2$ to obtain $$(y^2)'' = 0.$$ Then if you integrate both sides once, you get an arbitrary constant $C_1$ on the right hand side, but what about the left hand side? Well, the left hand side is $(y^2)''$ which means you've differentiated the function $y^2$ twice. Now you integrate the function once, which undoes one of these differentiations (which is why I prefer the term antidifferentiation to integration) . . .

Comment: . . .  so you are left with $$(y^2)' = C_1.$$ Now integrate both sides once more. On the left you undo the differentiation so you are left with the function $y^2$, and on the right hand side you obtain $C_1x + C_2$. That is, you arrive at $$y^2 = C_1x + C_2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your equation as

$$y y''+y'^2=0$$

which in turn may be written as

$$\frac{d}{dx} (y y') = 0$$

which means that

$$y y' = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx} (y^2) = \frac{1}{2} C_1$$

which means that $y$ satisfies

$$y(x)^2 = C_1 x+C_2$$

for constants $C_1$ and $C_2$, which are found from your initial conditions.